# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast?

Tags: string, list, visual-studio, flutter, dart

How can I fix that? I can't run the code because there is an error at String

```
        Text(
          questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'] as String,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 30),
        ),
        ...(questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
          return Answer(_answerQuestions, answer);
        }).toList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'] as String

questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'] as List<String>
```

How can `questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText']` be a `String` and a `List<String>` at the same time?

I can't know for sure since you didn't show whats inside of `questions` variable and we don't know what you want to do but you probably want to do something like this:

```
...(questions as List<Map<String, dynamic>>).map((question) {
  return Answer(_answerQuestions, question['questionText']);
}).toList()
```

Comment: add the value of questions and I can more easily help you, I cannot guess whats inside questions

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do an online course at Udemy (flutter) and this code was shown, to load the questions & answers by a quiz:

```
    Question(
      questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'],
    ),

    ...(questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
      return Answer(_answerQuestions, answer);
    }).toList()
```

but actually it doesn't work. I tried to put 'as String' to the first Line, but the Emulator does show an error. So I tried your Version but it doesn't helped me

Comment: what line gives you the error?? also, whats the value of questions variable??

Comment: questions[_questionsIndex]['questionText'] //this line gives an error and the value is of the variable is var _questionsIndex = 0;

Comment: const questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'What ist your fav color?',
      'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Magenta', 'Orange']
    },
etc..

Comment: I've edited the question from List<Map<String, String>> to List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Comment: finally it worked, ty so much. I will take a lokk at it slowly to understand it.

Comment: go for it, if you need help you can make a question and mark me with @ so I can try and help, good luck

Comment: so, there is a last thing I think:
question['questionText']... now my answers are also questions . How can I load my answer options in the Buttons? ...questions['answers'] doesn't work.

Comment: try: questions[_questionsIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map(

Comment: now it worked !